# tcolorbox with a header, a footer and a watermark

Tags: tcolorbox

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[table]{standalone}
\usepackage{polyglossia, lipsum}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{mybox}[2][]{%
  enhanced,
  before upper=\setlength{\parskip}{\bigskipamount},
  boxrule=2mm,
  bottomrule=9mm,
  watermark zoom=1,
  watermark color=black,
  watermark opacity=1,
  clip watermark,
  watermark text={\rotatebox{45}{Watermark}},
  overlay={%
    \node[white, font=\small, anchor=south, text width=\textwidth] at (frame.south) {%
        Footer \\ With Two Lines};},
  title=#2,#1}

\newcommand{\xxbody}{
\lipsum[1]
}

\newcommand{\xxheading}{
  Header \\ With Two Lines
}

\begin{document}

\begin{mybox}{\LARGE \xxheading{}}

  \xxbody{}

\end{mybox}

\end{document}
```

Here is the interesting thing. With the code as it is, I get header and footer. But no watermark. Switch off the footer by commenting the overlay out, and watermark emerges.

How do I get all the three elements --- header, footer and watermark?

This is a sequel to the question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/592481/multiline-footer-in-tcolorbox).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

If you follow this recomendation:

```
\documentclass[table]{standalone}
\usepackage{polyglossia,lipsum}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{mybox}[2][]{%
  enhanced,
  before upper=\setlength{\parskip}{\bigskipamount},
  boxrule=2mm,
  bottomrule=9mm,
  watermark zoom=1,
  watermark color=black,
  watermark opacity=.51,
  clip watermark,
  watermark text={\rotatebox{45}{Watermark}},
  overlay app={%
    \node[white, font=\small, anchor=south, text width=\textwidth] at (frame.south) {%
        Footer \\ With Two Lines};
    },
  title=#2,
  #1}

\newcommand{\xxbody}{
\lipsum[1]
}

\newcommand{\xxheading}{
  Header \\ With Two Lines
}

\begin{document}

\begin{mybox}{\LARGE \xxheading{}}

  \xxbody{}

\end{mybox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. That was perfect.